# call javascript function with arguments within php echo statement

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to call a javascript function within php that will pop up a confirmation button. If the user presses yes, then it will proceed onto the page, otherwise it'll stay on the same page. I wrote it, but I have no idea what's wrong.

php:

```
echo "<a href='edit_members.php?id=$studentid'>Edit</a> or <a href=\"javascript:deleteMembers('del_member.php', '$studentid');\">Delete</a><br/><br/>";
```

javascript (i placed it right before the  tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteMembers(url, id) {
       var deleteMemberConfirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
       if(deleteMemberConfirmation) {
         window.location="http://mvcsf.com/admin/"+url+"?"+id;
        }
       else {
         window.location="http://mvcsf.com/admin/view_members.php";
       }     
     }
</script>
```

I enabled `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);` at the top of the page, but it's not returning anything. What did I do wrong?

Edit: I changed the variable names to deleteMemberConfirmation, but still nothing works. I just click the link, but nothing happens.

Comment: What happens when you load this page? Do you get a blank white screen? Does it look right but the button doesn't work? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved keyword in javascript, and not a valid variable name!

And you got the quotes wrong:

```
"<a href=\"javascript:deleteMembers('del_member.php', '$studentid');\">";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `'` as a designator in your HTML *AND* in your JS. You will have to use it in one place and `"` in others.

A working version would be something like:

```
echo "<a href=\"edit_members.php?id=$studentid\">Edit</a> or <a href=\"javascript:deleteMembers('del_member.php', '$studentid');\">Delete</a><br/><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For your echo, be careful when using single quote `'` and double quote `"`. A single quote will be closed when it meets another single quote unless it is escaped like this `\'`. The same goes for double quote.

I'm not 100% sure if you can use javascript inside **href**, but another solution is to use onclick when calling javascript function, and just use `javascript:void(0)` or `#` for **href** attribute.

```
echo "<a href='edit_members.php?id=$studentid'>Edit</a> or <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"deleteMembers('del_member.php', '$studentid');\">Delete</a><br/><br/>";
```

As for the delete, change the delete word to something else (I.e: `del`), because **delete** is a reserved word for javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteMembers(url, id) {
    var del = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if(del) {
        window.location="http://mvcsf.com/admin/"+url+"?"+id;
    }
    else {
        window.location="http://mvcsf.com/admin/view_members.php";
    }
}
</script>
```